# Collision detection between PictureBoxes in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, collision

I've 2 pictureboxes on my Form, One is a moving one, whose directions are controlled by the keys, and other is a stable one, How is it possible to detect a collision between them.....Here is what I've tried; but failed.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private enum disha { up, down, left, right };
        private disha ekdisha = disha.down;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                ekdisha = disha.up;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                ekdisha = disha.down;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                ekdisha = disha.left;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                ekdisha = disha.right;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Top <= 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.Top = 0;
            }


            if (ekdisha == disha.up)
            {
                pictureBox1.Top -= 3;
            }

            else if (ekdisha == disha.down)
            {
                pictureBox1.Top += 3;
            }

            else if (ekdisha == disha.left)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left -= 3;
            }

            else if (ekdisha == disha.right)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left += 3;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pictureBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something is collided");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Looks good. Except that you should do the check when something changes, not in the `Form.Load` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the code for checking the bounds (which you have now written in Form1_Load) in a separate function and call it from timer1_Tick